# Using .net core web app in another .net core web app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create a .net core web application (or some kind of .net core service) which do web scraping from various web sites, and writes result to database.

Then I need to create another .net core web app in which I will do some actions with data from the FIRST app. However I should be able to update database by starting FIRST application from SECOND app by clicking button.

What is the best way to do this? 
1) I need to use .net core. 
2) I need that it be two apps, because I should be able to use FIRST application somewhere else, for example in THIRD application. 
3) Do I need to create some kind of .net core service. Or do separate apps, and then some how link them?

Comment: Sounds like your "first" application should probably be an API really (as opposed to an MVC app with a GUI), then you can make a simple HTTP request to it to trigger whatever actions you want, or request data from it. But if this "scraping" takes a long time, as it might, then perhaps you want to actually offload that job to a longer-running task or separate Service, and not run it all within the context of a HTTP request. This kind of architecture discussion is generally considered a bit broad (and potentially opinion-based) for SO, though.

Comment: And if I request "first" app from "Second" app to do something, I will be able to use "Second" app while "first" doing its job?

Comment: @Dov95 that is called an asynchronous task, for that you might need to check Task or Thread concepts/examples

Answer (score 1):

The questions is quite broad but goes my broad answer too ;-)

1. Write a .Net Core service that has two main methods: `scrapData` and `getData`, the the `scrapData` puts data into the Database after the scrapping takes place
2. Second app references and uses the service you created on step 1 and calls the `getData` method to obtain the scrapped data

Step 1 could also be a WebApi with a exposed method that you call from any other app when needed. This depends on your arquitecture limitations (but consier @ADyson comments regardin this option)

For more reference visit these sites

- https://stackify.com/creating-net-core-windows-services/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api